# Improving Secure Password Generator

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Simple Password Generator Example:

```js
function randomPassword() {
    var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +
       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" + 
                "1234567890" +
                "@\#\-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\";'<>?,.\/",
     pass  = "",
        PL    = 10;
    
    for (var x = 0; x < PL; x++) {
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        pass += chars.charAt(i);
    }
    return pass;
}

function generate() {
    myform.row_password.value = randomPassword();
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" method="post" action="">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="row_password" type="text" size="40">&nbsp;
                <input type="button" class="button" value="Generate" onClick="generate();" tabindex="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

### Improving Functionality Questions

**1). Obtaining All Values Within Variable**

Taking the base script above, how can I call `chars.length` and `chars.charAt(i)` where `chars` equals all the values within `Chars`?

```
var Chars = {};
    Chars.abc   = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    Chars.ABE   = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
    Chars.Num   = "1234567890";
    Chars.Sym   = "@\#\-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\";'<>?,.\/";
```

**2). Implementing a checkbox system for less advanced password**

To generate a less advanced password, such as not including symbox via unchecking a checkbox, how can I make it so only `Chars.abc`, `Chars.ABE`, and `Chars.Num` values are used?

**3). Equally Divide Password Length By `Chars`**

Round down (Password length / `Chars` used ), ie; the example used in this question generates a 10 character password and uses all charecters, therefore there would be a minimum of 2 of each `Chars`.

Comment: My first thought when seeing anyone trying to write their own password functions is: don't. It's a fun exercise, but others have written much more secure, flexible packages already.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @AutumnLeonard however I've been finding a lot of password generators and strength checkers don't all have the functions I'd like. I'm wanting to somewhat merge some features others have for a simple, easy to use feature on my site.

Comment: `chars.ABE = chars.abc.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Thank you @KevinB, not only is this useful but you made me spot a typo whereas `Chars.ABE` should be `Chars.ABC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd functionality is missing and will probably be way more sophisticated. But this is a simple solution to the 1st and 2nd ones.

```js
var output = document.getElementsByTagName('output')[0];

var Chars = {};
    Chars.length = 16;
    Chars.abc   = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    Chars.ABE   = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
    Chars.Num   = "1234567890";
    Chars.NumRequired = true;
    Chars.Sym   = "@\#\-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\";'<>?,.\/";

var generator = new randomPasswordGenerator(Chars);

var simpleGenerator = new randomPasswordGenerator({
    length: 6,
    abc: 'abc',
    Num: '0'
});

var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    button.addEventListener('click', clickFunction);

var checkbox = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

function clickFunction () {
  if (checkbox.checked) output.textContent = simpleGenerator.randomPassword();
  else output.textContent = generator.randomPassword();
}

function randomPasswordGenerator(opts) {
    for(var p in opts) this[p] = opts[p];
    this.randomPassword = randomPassword;
}

function randomPassword() {
    var chars = (this.abc || "") +
                (this.ABE || "") + 
                (this.Num || "") +
                (this.Sym || ""),
     pass  = [],
        PL    = this.length;
    if (this.NumRequired) {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.Num.length);
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * PL);
        pass[i] = this.Num[r];
    }
    for (var x = 0; x < PL; x++) {
        if(!pass[x]) {
          var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
          pass[x] = chars.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return pass.join('');
}
```

```css
output {
  margin: 12px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<button>Generate</button>
  <input type="checkbox">Simple
  <output></output>
```

Comment: Whoever has downrated this answer, could they please comment to as why? Also @rafaelcastrocouto, your simple version, is there a way to make it so that there is always a number in the password?

Comment: That downvote is the kinda thing that keeps me from helping more ppl. I updated the answer so you can use the property NumRequired to make sure at least one char will be a number; I guess if you read the code carefully you will make your way to better solutions!